# How to optimize .NET EF Core bulk insert?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, insert, bulkinsert

I'm building an app for ordering food at school. This requires the end user to add accounts for the different types (head secretariat, teacher, pupil,..).

I made a reliable interface to do so but it takes 111 seconds to add 1000 pupils because of all the queries it needs to go through for one insert.

this is the code for insert:

```
public async Task<List<FullPupil>> AddPupilAccountsBySchoolId(List<FullPupil> pupils, string schoolId, string password, string hashedPassword, Types type) {
        foreach (FullPupil pupil in pupils) {
            Accounts checkAccount = await _context.Accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Email == pupil.Email);

            if (checkAccount == null) {
                Accounts newAccount = new Accounts() {
                    Email = pupil.Email,
                    FirstTime = true,
                    FirstTimePassword = password,
                    Password = hashedPassword,
                    Name = pupil.Name,
                    SurName = pupil.SurName,
                    EmailSend = false,
                };

                await _context.Accounts.AddAsync(newAccount);
                checkAccount = newAccount;
            }

            AccountsTypes checkAccountsTypes = await _context.AccountsTypes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.AccountId == checkAccount.AccountId && a.TypeId == type.TypeId);

            if (checkAccountsTypes == null) {
                AccountsTypes accountsTypes = new AccountsTypes() {
                    AccountId = checkAccount.AccountId,
                    TypeId = type.TypeId,
                };

                await _context.AccountsTypes.AddAsync(accountsTypes);
            }

            Pupils checkPupil = await _context.Pupils.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.AccountId == checkAccount.AccountId);

            if (checkPupil == null) {
                Pupils newPupil = new Pupils() {
                    AccountId = checkAccount.AccountId,
                    ClassId = Guid.Parse(pupil.Class[0].Id),
                    CodeId = Guid.Parse(pupil.Code[0].Id),
                    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                };

                await _context.Pupils.AddAsync(newPupil);
            } else {
                checkPupil.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }

            pupil.AccountId = checkAccount.AccountId;
        }

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return pupils;
    }
```

(I am aware that all accounts will have the same password, this is just for testing purpose)

This is the database structure this uses:

[image: Structure of database]

(a classId in Pupils is linked to a unique class of a school)

One account can have multiple functions or be the same function on multiple schools so for example: a teacher can be teacher on multiple schools and at the same time a parent on a different school. (AccountsTypes is a many-to-many relationship between Accounts and Types)

Because of this, the insert needs to check if the account already exists and if it doesn't, add it, otherwise do nothing and go on and check if it is already a pupil in this school and if it isn't, add it, otherwise do nothing and so on.

I thought of a solution by just adding everything and if it already exists, just update it without first checking but I couldn't find anything about how to do that.

So how can I optimize this so it doesn't take so long and doesn't have to check if it already exists and maybe insert it in one addAsync so it adds it in all the related tables?

This also needs to be really reliable so it doesn't fail.

Comment: EF is not designed for bulk operations. If you OK, I'll show how to do that with third-party extensions.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv If you can suggest a third-party extension that I can use for free and for commercial use without the need to let the users know I'm using this extension?

Comment: For sure. MIT license.

Comment: Take a look at https://entityframework-extensions.net/ (very very good but you need to pay), or https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Comment: I tried EFCore.BulkExtension by borisdj but the documentation about relationships isn't that great and I couldn't make it work (it worked but it didn't update the guid so in the related table, the foreign id is always 00000... what made it crash).

Answer (score 0):

EF itself is not designed for Bulk Operations, everything should go through `ChangeTracker`.

I would suggest to use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators).

Library has temporary tables support and it's onw LINQ translator, which makes `linq2db` very powerful for ETL tasks.

```cs
public async Task<List<FullPupil>> AddPupilAccountsBySchoolId(List<FullPupil> pupils, string schoolId, string password, string hashedPassword, Types type) 
{
    using var db = _context.CreateLinqToDBConnection();

    // Preprocess data for temporary table
    var pupilsProjection = pupils.Select(pupil => new 
    {
        pupil.Email,
        pupil.Name,
        pupil.SurName,
        ClassId = Guid.Parse(pupil.Class[0].Id),
        CodeId = Guid.Parse(pupil.Code[0].Id),
    });

    // here we create temporary table and execute BulkCopy for inserting items into database
    using var tempPupil = await db.CreateTempTableAsync(pupilsProjection, tableName: "TempPupils");

    var missingAccounts = 
        from t in tempPupil
        join a in _context.Accounts on t.Email equals a.Email into gj
        from a in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where a == null
        select t;

    // Inserting missed accounts
    await missingAccounts.InsertAsync(_context.Accounts.ToLinqToDBTable(), pupil =>
        new Accounts 
        {
            Email = pupil.Email,
            FirstTime = true,
            FirstTimePassword = password,
            Password = hashedPassword,
            Name = pupil.Name,
            SurName = pupil.SurName,
            EmailSend = false,
        }
    );

    // Helper query for Acount <-> Pupil association
    var pupilWithAccount =
        from t in tempPupil
        join a in _context.Accounts on t.Email equals t.Email
        select new 
        {
            Pupil = t,
            Account = a
        };

    var missingAccountTypes = 
        from pa in in pupilWithAccount
        join at in _context.AccountsTypes on new { pa.Account.AccountId, pa.Account.TypeId } equals { at.AccountId, type.TypeId } into gj
        from at in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where at == null
        select pa.Account;
    
    // Inserting missing Account Types
    await missingAccountTypes.InsertAsync(_context.AccountsTypes.ToLinqToDBTable(), 
        a => new AccountsTypes()
        {
            AccountId = a.AccountId,
            TypeId = type.TypeId,
        }
    );

    var missingPupils = 
        from pa in pupilWithAccount
        join p in _context.Pupils on pa.AccountId equals p.AccountId into gj
        from p in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where p == null
        select pa;

    // Insering missing pupils
    await missingPupils.InsertAsync(_context.Pupils.ToLinqToDBTable(), 
        pa => new Pupil
        {
            AccountId = pa.Account.AccountId,
            ClassId = pa.Pupil.ClassId,
            CodeId = pa.Pupil.CodeId,
            ModifiedDate = Sql.CurrentTimestamp,
        }
    );

    // retrieve current account Id
    var newIds = await pupilWithAccount
        .Select(pa => new { paAccount.Account.AccountId, paAccount.Account.Email })
        .ToDictionaryAsyncLinqToDB(x => x.Email, x => x.AccountId);

    foreach (var pupil in pupils)
    {
        if (newIds.TryGetValue(pupil.Email, out var accountId))
            pupil.AccountId = accountId;
    }

    return pupils;
}
```

Please note that I have written this sample from memory and there can be typos.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this next week when I start optimizing the project. I'll let you know.